# Phonegap Media Streaming is not working on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, audio-streaming

I'm using the Media class of the phonegap to stream an audio from a url which the format of the url is the ip with the port. On the android is working fine, the sound is playing. On the iOS is not playing and I don't know why. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Here is the function of my streaming.

```
function playAudio(src) {
    // Create Media object from src
    setAudioPosition("Please wait...");
    my_media = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);

    // Play audio
    myMedia.play({ playAudioWhenScreenIsLocked : false })
    $('.jp-play').hide();
    $('.jp-pause').show();
    // Update my_media position every second
    if (mediaTimer == null) {
        mediaTimer = setInterval(function() {
            // get my_media position
            my_media.getCurrentPosition(
                // success callback
                function(position) {
                    if (position > -1) {
                        setAudioPosition("Playing");
                    }
                },
                // error callback
                function(e) {
                    console.log("Error getting pos=" + e);
                    setAudioPosition("Error: " + e);
                }
            );
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

On the xml of the project I have added the ip of the server in the whitelist but again is not working. How I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Hello I found the solution. I have used the library of devgeeks. here is the link for everyone who will have the same problem 
https://github.com/devgeeks/ExampleHTML5AudioStreaming

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem months ago, the phonegap player was not working on ios but it did on android, what a did was to make my player native (Objetive c) and call it form de phonegap side (javascript).

by Making a plugin

```
- (void)play:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command{

NSString* scr = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];

CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = nil;
NSString* javaScript = nil;

@try {

    if (scr != nil) {

        if (player.isPreparedToPlay) {


            player.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:scr];
            [player play];

        }else {


            MPMoviePlayerController* objplayer =[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:scr]];

            self.player = objplayer;
            [self.player prepareToPlay];

            player.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
            player.view.hidden = YES;
            player.useApplicationAudioSession = YES;
            [player play];


        }
        pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK];
        javaScript = [pluginResult toSuccessCallbackString:@"respuesta"];
    }
} @catch (id exception) {
    pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_JSON_EXCEPTION messageAsString:[exception reason]];
    javaScript = [pluginResult toErrorCallbackString:@"respuesta con error"];
}

[self writeJavascript:javaScript];
}
```

After that, you call the plugin in the config.xml

then in your javascript

```
Cordova.exec(null, null, "playMusic", "Play", [url,url]);
```