# Stream audio in my app

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio-streaming

I am developing mobile web app for iOS and android in html5.
How can i stream music from another url in my page? (like radio).
There is already someone who plays the music and he can give me his url/i.p or whatever.
I just need to stream it in my app.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's useful link:
http://www.joeldare.com/wiki/play_an_mp3_audio_stream_in_phonegap

Or see this solution:
[Phonegap Media Streaming is not working on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17875385/solved-phonegap-media-streaming-is-not-working-on-ios)